# SQL join select based on specific table values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Goal: Select all items if the `users_allergy =0` but filter items out when the `allergy=1`

`User_peanut_allergy = 0` means the user has no peanut allergy.

`User_peanut_allergy = 1` means the user has that allergy. Do not display nuts

An allergy item is set to 1 in the user table and nutrition table. If the user has no allergies then the table value is 0.

This works if a user has no allergies but fails when there is an allergy (set to `1`). It fails since `>=0`. I need to distinguish matching `greater than 0` but not when the `users allergy is a 1`.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Nutrition]
INNER JOIN Users ON Nutrition.contains_gluten >= Users.gluten_allergy
    AND Nutrition.contains_nuts >= Users.peanut_allergy
    AND Nutrition.contains_fish >= Users.fish_allergy
    AND Nutrition.contains_soy >= Users.soy_allergy
    AND Nutrition.contains_dairy >= Users.dairy_allergy
WHERE Users.username = 'Kyle';
```

How can I put an if statement to determine if the user doesn't have an allergy then all items are displayed?

```
IF (Users.peanut_allergy == 0)
    SELECT everything including allergy items
ELSE
    JOIN
    WHERE contains_nuts = 0
```

Sample Data: https://pastebin.com/2knYTcHk
Test a User table with `0 for no allergy` and `1 for allergy`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN. (I.e. no IF...)

Comment: I added some sample data

Comment: This is a confusing question. Do you just want any rows in `Nutrition` that the row in `Users` doesn't have an allergy for? Also why are you using `>=` instead of just `=`? Can the `contains` values be something other than `1` or `0`?

Comment: The goal is to select all items if the `user_allergy=0` and if `user_allergy=1` then select `filtered items <0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand exactly what you are looking for, but try something like this:

```
SELECT * from [dbo].[Nutrition]
INNER JOIN Users
 ON (Users.gluten_allergy = 0 or Nutrition.contains_gluten = 0)
AND (Users.peanut_allergy = 0 or Nutrition.contains_nuts = 0)
AND (Users.fish_allergy = 0 or Nutrition.contains_fish = 0)
AND (Users.soy_allergy = 0 or Nutrition.contains_soy = 0)
AND (Users.dairy_allergy = 0 or Nutrition.contains_dairy = 0)
where Users.username = 'Kyle';
```

Each one follows the same pattern. Either the User has no allergy, and the condition is true, or the food in the Nutrition table doesn't contain that ingredient. In other words, the only way that the join fails is if the user has the allergy and the food contains that ingredient.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 1/0 combinations, you can use multiplication:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Nutrition] JOIN
     Users
     ON Nutrition.contains_gluten * (1 - Users.gluten_allergy) = 1 OR
        Nutrition.contains_nuts * (1 - Users.peanut_allergy) = 1 OR
        Nutrition.contains_fish * (1 - Users.fish_allergy) = 1 OR
        Nutrition.contains_soy * (1 - Users.soy_allergy) = 1 OR
        Nutrition.contains_dairy * (1 - Users.dairy_allergy) = 1
WHERE Users.username = 'Kyle';
```

I also think that just `>` would work.

Comment: OR is nice but if the food contains an allergy it is still matched due to being `1 >= 1` when 1 should only match if `Users.allergy == 0`

Comment: This kind of works but I just noticed if there are multiple food allergies then the `OR` includes results that shouldn't show. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the other condition in the filter to get the required output. If that whats you are looking for this will make sure you only select data without any allergy.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Nutrition] JOIN
     Users
     ON Nutrition.contains_gluten >= Users.gluten_allergy OR
        Nutrition.contains_nuts >= Users.peanut_allergy OR
        Nutrition.contains_fish >= Users.fish_allergy OR
        Nutrition.contains_soy >= Users.soy_allergy OR
        Nutrition.contains_dairy >= Users.dairy_allergy
WHERE  Users.peanut_allergy > 0 and Users.gluten_allergy > 0 and  Users.fish_allergy > 0 and Users.soy_allergy > 0 and Users.dairy_allergy > 0
and Users.username = 'Kyle'
```